# How can I compute mathematically the longest random walk one can take so that on average you will end up 5 or fewer blocks from home?

Tags: statistics

Suppose you live in a city with the streets forming a rectangular
grid. You leave home for a walk. At each intersection you choose a random direction (N,
E, S or W), and backtracking is permitted. Once you’re finished with your walk, you
check to see how far away you are from where you started. If you are more than 5 blocks
away, you need transportation and you must pay for it; otherwise, you can walk home.
What is the longest random walk you can take so that on average you’ll end up 5 blocks
or fewer from your home? You can assume a limit for the longest walk, such as 50.

P.S: I know that a way of solving this problem is by using Monte Carlo simulation, but I also need to know how I can compute this mathematically.

Comment: Is this in the 1-norm, meaning that (1,1) and (2,0) are equally far from where you started?

Comment: Start with the 1D problem where you go North and South with equal probability.  The mean position stays zero.  What is the variance of one step?  Variances add.  When you say on average do you mean the average of the absolute distance or the median of the distribution?

Comment: Also, do you want the longest walk such that the average distance is at most 5, or do you want the longest walk such that the probability that the distance exceeds 5 is less than some tolerance? The latter seems a bit more natural to me, but it's just part of the modeling assumptions.